# Delphi 2007 IDE Forms Arrange

Tags: delphi

I wondered if there was any keyboard control sequence to return Delphi 2007 IDE back to a "standard positions layout" ?

i.e. Menu bar at top, object inspector on left, working area in middle ... Components tool bar palette .. Project manager window  ..

Maybe this is wishful thinking?

Comment: No, there is no keyboard command sequence (afaik). But there is a dropdown, originally located in the menu / toolbar. In this dropdown there was four items: `<none>`, `Classic Undocked`, `Debug Layout` and `Default Layout`. In addition there was a possibility to add your own layouts to the list. If you haven't changed the layout and saved using the standard names, you can revert to the original layout.

Comment: There is also a submenu under View where you can select the Desktops. This can be done with the keyboard (but not with a keyboard shortcut). There is also an expert in GExperts which re-selects the currently selected Desktop, so it reverts any manual changes to it you have made but not saved. You can assign a keyboard shortcut to this expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tom Brunberg and dummzeuch for your replies.

Yes, I use GExperts. for ctrl-F12 unit find/index tool which is great.

I had success with Tom's suggestion.

I switched the View | Desktops option to "Classic Undocked" and then back to "< None >" option.

Menu choices in Delphi 2007 as per this picture:

[image]